# create icons in flutter pdf?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf, icons

I need a add icons in flutter pdf. This was completely different when compared with add icons in flutter. I am using https://pub.dev/packages/pdf this package.

Here is the code :

```
pw.Icon(pw.IconData(0xe047));
```

Error was :

```
ArgumentError (Invalid argument (string): Contains invalid characters.: "")
```

Answer (score 2):

check whether PdfGoogleFonts.materialIcons() is added under page theme:

```
theme: pw.ThemeData.withFont(
  base: await PdfGoogleFonts.openSansRegular(),
  bold: await PdfGoogleFonts.openSansBold(),
  icons: await PdfGoogleFonts.materialIcons(), // this line
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your custom icons using [www.fluttericon.com](https://www.fluttericon.com/)

using pw.ThemeData.withFont like this

```
var pathToFile = await rootBundle.load('- your icon font file (.ttf) -');
final ttf = pw.Font.ttf(pathToFile);

// load ttf to pdf theme
final theme = pw.ThemeData.withFont(
                  base: await PdfGoogleFonts.robotoCondensedRegular(),
                  bold: await PdfGoogleFonts.robotoCondensedBold(),
                  icons: ttf,
               );

final pw.Icon(pw.IconData(customIcon.icon.codePoint), size: 10)
```

output after rendering pdf file is,

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To use Material Icons in **Pdf** package you just import **material** as **mt** and **pdf** as **dynamic**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as mt;
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart';
```

Now take the Icon from the Material library and pass its codepoints to IconData Constructor in PDF Library now you can easily use the IconData instance in PDF Icon() class.

```
Icon(IconData(mt.Icons.check.codePoint),
                  color:
                  value PdfColors.grey,
                  size: 18,
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the printing module

https://pub.dev/packages/printing

```
dependencies:
  printing: ^5.6.0
```

import the package in your dart file

```
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
```

And set your theme with:

```
final pdf = pw.Document();

pdf.addPage(
  pw.Page(
    theme: pw.ThemeData.withFont(
      base: await PdfGoogleFonts.varelaRoundRegular(),
      bold: await PdfGoogleFonts.varelaRoundRegular(),
      icons: await PdfGoogleFonts.materialIcons(),
    ),
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
    build: (pw.Context context) {
      return pw.Center(
        child: pw.Text("Hello World"),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

The source of this answer is here

https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/blob/master/demo/lib/examples/resume.dart

Comment: you will need these codepoints to find out the correct icon
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/font/MaterialIcons-Regular.codepoints